# Graphically represent relations between objects (not classes!) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graph, associations, dot

I have two classes in one of my Rails apps that have a many-to-many relationship.  I'm trying to tidy them up (ie delete a bunch and move a bunch more) and it would be great if I could actually see how they link up.  (I can print out a text file listing each instance of class A and then list it's associated class B objects under it, but this isn't quite hitting the spot.)

In the past, I've used gems (like http://rails-erd.rubyforge.org/gallery.html) which do this for **classes**, ie they build an entity-relationship diagram `.dot` file.  Now I want to do it for **instances** of two classes.  Has anyone seen anything like this?